# Jetpack Compose ViewModel Updae Flow

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I use Paging in ViewMode, and Paging returns Flow

```
class WindViewModel : BaseViewModel() {

    lateinit var windList : Flow<PagingData<Wind>>

    fun getWindList(path: String) {
        windList = Pager(PagingConfig(pageSize = 20)) {
            WindSource(path, user.id)
        }.flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope)
    }

    fun like(wind: Wind) {

    }

}
```

If I need to update Flow in the like method, how do I update it?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a StateFlow for `windList` because it lets you directly update the value of the flow with the `.value` property without needing to use a coroutine scope:

```
private val _windList: MutableStateFlow(Wind())
val windList: StateFlow<Wind> = _windList
```

and then update your flow in `fun like(wind: Wind)` accordingly:

```
fun like(wind: Wind) {
  _windList.value = windList.value.copy(##update changed properties here##)
}
```